# What are some alternatives to document.execCommand to select and copy text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code the uses the following lines:

```
document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
document.execCommand('copy', false, null);
```

And it works great. However, Mozilla has marked this command as obsolete. What is a better way of doing this, possibly with React or plain Javascript?

Comment: I have had luck with https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-polyfill

Comment: You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write